# The port on client side to access APN(Apple Push Notification)'s service

Tags: ios, push-notification

According to [**apple docs**](http://support.apple.com/kb/ts1629), it mentioned 2195, 2196 and 5223 for APN's service. But I have no idea which port on **client side** should be opened to access APN's service.

My service provider ask me to provide the format of `FROM : <server> <port> TO: <server> <port>` so that they can help me to open the port access on my server. Anyone could give me some hints?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to care about ports on client side! Your provider need to know only device token. [This](http://blog.boxedice.com/2009/07/10/how-to-build-an-apple-push-notification-provider-server-tutorial/) will be helpful to understand how it works.

OK, that's what I've done in my app:

```
 [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:(UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge | UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound | UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert)];
```

in appDidFinishedLaunchingWithOptions
And two methods to add in AppDelegate:

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)app didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData *)devToken {
    self.registered = YES;
//Сustom sending to my server  
  [[pushHandler sharedInstance] sendToken:devToken];
}

- (void)application:(UIApplication *)app 
didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError:(NSError *)err {
    NSLog(@"Error in registration. Error: %@", err);
}
```

And that's all. If needed port is closed, you will get error. I've never got error because of closed port.

Comment: Ok, I sees someone said "Make sure the outgoing port 2195 is open." So the client should also opened port 2195 to access APN?

Comment: Added some more info to answer.